Is Gödel reducible to Cantor?
I have worked out a putative proof of Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem, that is shorter and more to the point; because it moves the assumption of completeness earlier. Is this proof known ? [Mind you it does not assume soundness; if you think the post is incomplete, please be specific because I no longer know what to make clearer.]
Here is the proof in question. As in Gödel's proof, say $S_m(n)$ indexes the $m$th well formed formula acting on input $n$. Then,

Assume consistency and completeness, i.e., for each sentence $S$, either there is a proof for $S$, or for $\lnot S$.

Form the predicate $P$ such that $P(S)= 1$ if the system proves $S$ and $0$ if it proves $\lnot S$. By assuming completeness earlier, this is true of the system.

Define $S^*(x) := \lnot P(S_x(x))$. Then $S^*(x)$ has proof characteristic function (called signature elsewhere): $P(S^*(x))$, $x=1,2,\dots$, which for every $x$ are all different from all other countable signatures
$P(S_m(x))$, $x=1,2,\dots$. This is a contradiction so (1) is false, hence INCOMPLETENESS.



Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The proof idea basically works and is really not any different then the usual use of the diagonalization lemma. The diagonalization lemma says that for a sufficiently strong arithmetical theory $T$ (Robinson arithmetic suffices) and a one-variable formula $\phi(x)$, there is a sentence $S$ such that $T\vdash S\leftrightarrow \phi(\ulcorner S\urcorner),$ and this is used in several variants of the proof of the first incompleteness theorem.
The reason I say it's not any different is because of how the diagonalization lemma is proved. We first, through great pains (which can be ameliorated by some tricks) show that the function $f$ taking an integer $n$ to the Gödel number of the sentence $\varphi_n(n)$ (where $\varphi_n$ is the formula with Gödel number $n$) is representable in $T$. Then we can define $f$ in the theory and it makes sense to write down the one-variable formula $\psi(x):=\phi(f(x))$, and then we take $S := \psi(\ulcorner \psi\urcorner)$ and check that we've dotted our t's and crossed our i's correctly (in particular the fact that $f$ is represented in $T,$ not merely expressed needs to be use). (To tie this out to the discussion in the comments, here $\psi $ is $\phi_5$ and so $\ulcorner \psi\urcorner = 5$.)
So you've essentially in-lined the proof of the diagonalization lemma, for the particular case of interest where $\phi$ the negation of a provability predicate, which will work, although a full justification would require going through all the same tedious details as in any standard proof.
Likewise, the strategy from that point on doesn't deviate too strongly from the Gödel sentence approach, but you push it through to a full contradiction under the assumption that $T$ is complete, which of course it must produce if you prove $T$ can't prove it. (You frame this in your question as just showing there can be no fixed point, when on the other hand there obviously must be, but the crux is the same.)
But this approach requires some form of soundness, not merely consistency, as it's perfectly possible for the fixed point sentence to be disprovable in a consistent $T$ (there are examples!). This is because it's possible for a consistent $T$ to prove something is provable when it really isn't... in this case the Gödel sentence.
However, it can be modified to produce a proof by contradiction that only relies on consistency. Essentially, you just need to use that completeness and consistency assumption to argue that you can make a better, decidable version of $P$... this version can't exist in real life but does under this (turns out contradictory) hypothetical. With the real $P$, $T$ can only necessarily prove positive instances of it... i.e. if there's a proof, $T$ can prove it, but if there isn't a proof, $T$ can't necessarily prove that.
But if $T$ were complete and consistent, then we could algorithmically decide provability (by just going through all the proofs and seeing whether the sentence or its negation comes up), so this would mean that $T$ should also be able to verify negative instances of provability, so there will be a predicate that works like this. But now the Gödel sentence (using this predicate) actually produces a contradiction, since if it were unprovable, it would provably unprovable, and hence provable (since it says it is unprovable).

thank you. Indeed the proof is close to Godel's one BUT : the contradiction in mine comes BEFORE the actual fixed point. I tried to find how close the actual reason of incompleteness is to Cantor's proof. And my argument shows it is exactly the same. [1] list elements [cantor: numbers / logic: predicates s(x),x=1,..]; [2], characterize the list by a property [cantor: decimal sequence/ logic: provability sequence of  s(x),x=1,..]; [3] observe that 'completeness' [cantor: of the list/ logic: of the system], produces the neg. diag of the property is a contradiction.

I agree with the points made by spaceisdarkgreen in their answer and comments to you. The main takeaways are:

It is very well-understood that the proofs of Cantor's theorem on uncountability of the reals, Tarski's theorem on undefinability of truth, Gödel's first incompleteness theorem, and even Russell's paradox all have the same core idea. This idea can be presented in terms of fixed-points, or in terms of diagonalization. The relationship between these two presentations is so well-understood that the fixed-point lemma is often called the "diagonal lemma". Here are some examples of places in the literatures where the relationship between Cantor's and Gödel's proofs are examined: (1) Naming and Diagonalization: from Cantor to Gödel to Kleene, by Gaifman. An even more explicit summary of the same material is given in this note by Gaifman. (2) The famous paper Diagonal arguments and Cartesian closed categories by Lawvere identifies (in category-theoretic language) the abstract principle unifying all these results. A less category-theoretic exposition is given by Yanofsky in his paper A Universal Approach to Self-Referential Paradoxes, Incompleteness and Fixed Points.

Your argument is a quite nice, efficient presentation of Gödel's argument in terms of diagonalization, rather than fixed-points. The argument you gave walks right up to proving the fixed-point/diagonal lemma without actually stating it, as explained in the answer by spaceisdarkgreen.

What you wrote does sweep under the rug all the careful work of Gödel coding, so developing it from scratch would be just as much work as traditional proofs of Gödel's theorem.

Your argument as written does require soundness (or sufficiently much soundness, in the form of $\omega$-consistency), as did Gödel's original proof. This dependency can be fixed using Rosser's trick, which is incorporated into modern proofs of Gödel's theorem.


My answer isn't going to add very much, just a more careful analysis of your argument to clarify where it uses soundness.
Let's examine your argument step-by-step. Let $T$ be a theory to which Gödel's theorem appplies. We assume for contradiction that $T$ is complete and consistent.
(1) By carrying out Gödel coding in $T$, we can code each formula $\varphi(x)$ by a natural number $\lceil \varphi(x)\rceil$. Let's write $\varphi_n(x)$ for the formula with code $n$. Further, there's a definable operation on pairs of natural numbers $(n,m)\mapsto \lceil \varphi_n(m)\rceil$, which substitutes $m$ for the free variable $x$ in the formula coded by $n$. And with a bit more coding work, there is a formula $P(x)$ in one free variable $x$ which means "$T\vdash\varphi_x$". This is all standard.
(2) Now let $\varphi^*(x)$ be the formula $\lnot P(\lceil\varphi_x(x)\rceil)$. By consistency and completeness, for each $n$, either $T\vdash \varphi^*(n)$ or $T\vdash \lnot \varphi^*(n)$.
(3) Now your assertion is that for every formula $\varphi(x)$ in one free variable $x$, there exists a natural number $m$ such that $T\vdash \varphi^*(m)$ iff $T\not\vdash \varphi(m)$, showing that our enumeration of formulas in one free variable is incomplete for a contradiction. In fact, if $m = \lceil \varphi(x)\rceil$ (so $\varphi(x)$ is $\varphi_m(x)$), we can take the natural number to be $m$.
Let's unpack the claimed equivalence. We have $T\vdash \varphi^*(m)$ if and only if $T\vdash \lnot P(\lceil\varphi_m(m)\rceil)$. To conclude, you would like this to be equivalent to $T\not\vdash \varphi_m(m)$. But for a sentence $\psi$ (like $\varphi_m(m)$), $T\not\vdash \psi$ does not imply $T\vdash \lnot P(\lceil\psi\rceil)$ in general. That is, we do not know that when $T$ proves $P(\psi)$, it's "telling the truth" and there is a real proof of $\psi$ from $T$ - we need soundness for this.
For example, taking $T$ to be $PA+\lnot\mathrm{Con}(PA)$ and $\psi$ to be a contradiction, $T\vdash P(\lceil\psi\rceil)$ (since $T$ proves that there is a proof of $\psi$ from the axioms of $PA$, and hence from $T$ itself), but $T\not\vdash \psi$ (since $T$ is consistent, as shown by Gödel!).

Thanks. Let me try to follow: indeed I construct phi*(x) as you say. Say phi* has gdl# 5, ie phi(5,.). Then for any phi, say phi(3,.) I suggest to compare provability of 3rd element: phi(5,3) vs phi(3,3).

i.e. compare P(~P(phi(3,3)) vs P(phi(3,3)). Abbrev. phi(3,3) as S, so we go to compare P(~P(S) ) to P(S).   case 1: if the right hand side, P(S), is system-true (meaning provable within system) then ~P(S) is system-false (not provable); and so P(~P(S)) is system false (by completeness).  case 2: if the right hand side, P(S), is system-false, then ~P(S) is system true, and P(~P(S)) is system true (by completeness). So I am seeing that the above comparison has different system-truth values, so I get contradiction. What do you say ?

@ConstantineFrangakis The error is going from "$\lnot P(S)$ is not provable" to "$P(\lnot P(S))$ is not provable". If the theory is not sound, it is entirely possible that there is a proof of $P(\lnot P(S))$, but no proof of $\lnot P(S)$.

Sure. But we can protect ourselves for that.  I look at qx def=p(phi(x,x)) and ask myself: what statement has opposite provality than the prov of qx ? If qx is provable then i define my phi*(x) as ~q(x), and the reverse. Consistency then forces contradiction. Right ?

@ConstantineFrangakis Sorry, I can't make any sense of your last comment. You're changing the meaning of $\varphi^*(x)$ from what you originally wrote, now? What formula is it, precisely?

Yes it is different (I only had thought that unsound meant that a statement can have P(S) even if S is in some objective way true outside the system; but I realize you (and the literature) means something else).  And what I am saying is that- it's OK, because we want a phi**(x) whose p(phi**(x)) flips the "sign" of p(phi(x,x)) of the diagonal. To do this, define the intermediate phi*(x) def = ~p(phi(x,x)). and check cases: (a) If {p(phi*(x)) differs from p(phi(x,x))} (the p of the diag), then accept phi*(x) as our phi**(x); but (b) if {p(phi*(x))= p(phi(x,x))}, then take phi**(x) as ~phi*(x).

@ConstantineFrangakis This "checking cases" is not actually something you can do syntactically within the system, since it relies on talking about what $T$ actually proves, rather than what $T$ proves it proves.

I'd be happy to know if my argument works even in a system that is unsound except for requiring that: {A & B}  is system-provable iff in truth {A is system provable} &_{in truth} {B is system provable}.

@ConstantineFrangakis I believe that your argument (and also Gödel's original argument) goes through assuming merely that if $T\vdash P(\varphi)$, then $T\vdash \varphi$. Or alternatively, assuming merely that $T\not\vdash P(\bot)$, i.e., that $T$ does not prove "$T$ is inconsistent."

Yes, I was also thinking that even if it did not do so for any phi, it would at least be reasonable to expect this, after some successive iterations of P(), i.e if the above phi is P(P(...P())) of some psi, because I could the take that property on the diagonal. Thank you for your help.

By the way, I understand your expertise sees my observation as obvious. But I (statistician and amateur logician), have always been interested in hierarchizing the reasons for why a result holds. It's like projecting the results into "principal component" understandings. For Godel's, (a) it seems that Cantor's {numbers exceed rationals} is not just a trick by Godel, but is almost an isomorphism; (b), and many people (+ me) take years of grasping such hierarchy and would benefit from guidance. Is there an outlet that would consider my writing something simple on this idea ? Thank you again.

@ConstantineFrangakis I edited the first bullet-point of my answer to indicate some explicit places in the literature where what you suggest has been done.

Thank you for the comments.

Dr. Kruckman, I am writing here because I have a related question, which I thought you are most likely to know its answer, or at least direct me to what two read. My question is what part of the "truth" in Tarski's theorem is important and what not.  Here it goes:   (next comment)

Consider the array S[m,n] of all predicates of a single free variable n (sorted by godel number m). Instead of "Truth", say there exists a mapping B on S[m,n] that is 0 or 1 (and we do not know it, say Mary knows it). Mary also observes that B is not constant, and she notes down two specific S's, say S0 and S1, for which she sees that B is 0, and 1 respectively.  Now, Mary defines a function D that flips B: D(n) = S0 if B(S[n,n]) = 1, and S1 if B(S[n,n]) = 0. It seems to me now, that D(.) cannot any of S[m, .] because Mary constructed it to have the opposite B signature of the diagonal.

My question: does that mean that B(S[m,n]) cannot be of the same nature (language) as S[m,n]  (like in the halting problem, where if there were a machine determining halting of Machine[m,n], it could create a new machine outside the list of machines). But if yes, why does the contradiction seem to arise also when B is simply computable by us (not restricted to Mary) ? Eg., B(S) = "the string of S in peano+logic has < 100 characters". Obviously B(S) is expressable itself in Peano+logic (right ?) Thank you. C Frangakis

@ConstantineFrangakis I recommend you post a new question (and please put in the effort to use proper formatting).

Alternatively, here's a hint to resolving the apparent paradox. At first glance, I believe what you've actually done is proved the following theorem: every definable equivalence-invariant function from Gödel codes to ${0,1}$ is constant. Here "$B$ is equivalence-invariant" means that if the formulas with Gödel codes $n$ and $m$ are equivalent, then $B(n)=B(m)$.

Thanks, but because this is not clear to me yet, I am going to create a new question.
